# Add/remove items to/from an HTML select list using jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Could somebody recommend some of the best strategies they've used to populate items in an HTML select list on the client side?

I'm using an ASP.NET MVC application and making use of jQuery.

The select list in question is simply a collection of strings which will need to be saved with the model.

I'd rather not have a server call for every item added and simply have everything posted once the form is saved.

Are there any plugins available that can make this easier? Would it be best to write my own pop-up form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to do a lot of manipulation and support older IE versions where `<select>` is a bit flaky, yes there is a plugin: [jQuery - Select box manipulation plugin](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/select/), thought it may be overkill for what you're doing.

The alternative is just using selectors for what's needed, for example:

```
function addItem(val, text) {
  $("#mySelect").append($("<option>", { value: val, text: text }));
}
function removeItem(val) {
  $("#mySelect option[value='"+val+"']").remove();
  //or:
  $("#mySelect option").filter(function(){ return this.value == val; }).remove();
}
```